# Django login authentication always returns none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-login

I am using django contrip auth for authenticate user. Signup function always working and register and login user successfully but after that I m logged out and try to login again but this time login function doesnt work.

I add this codes my settings file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

My User model seems like that in models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

My Login and Register function

```
def dlogin(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request, "login.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # Attempt to sign user in
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            cur_user = request.user
            return render(request,'index.html',{
                'success':'login successful',
                'user':cur_user
            })
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html',{
                'error':'Invalid username and/or password.'
            })
```

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return render(request, 'signup.html')

    # Get form information
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]

    # Ensure password matches confirmation
    
    if password != confirmation:
       return render(request,'register.html',{
           'message':'Passwords dont match'
       })

    # Attempt to create new user
    user = User.objects.create_user(username,password)
    user.save()

    login(request, user)

    return redirect('index')
```

I did some research and couldn't find any problem in my code. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: The issue is with `@csrf_exempt` decorator on the view, how can you make a login and logout without `crsf_token`? It's necessary.

Comment: @SunderamDubey login view has not csrf_exempt decorator

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

I change this in signup function

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username,password)
```

to this

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
```

and it works but i dont know why